# Unable to create organization and space in PCF using CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, cloud-foundry, pivotal-web-services

I have created the PCF account in run.pivotal.io platform but not able to create org and space in UI as PCF is not allowing new account and showing the message "We will no longer be accepting any new PWS account sign-ups after September 17, 2020"
I tried creating the org and space from CLI(admin mode) but no luck.

ErrorMessage:

Creating org NP as ---@gmail.com...
You are not authorized to perform the requested action
FAILED.

***while creating the user below are error logs***:

"C:\Users\s\git\pcf-crash-course-with-spring-boot>cf create-user ------@gmail.com ss

Creating user --------@gmail.com...

Error creating user -----------@gmail.com.

Post https://uaa.run.pivotal.io/Users: read tcp 192.168.225.214:54659->3.220.155.194:443: wsarecv:

An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
FAILED"

Comment: Tried creating one more PCF account and it is observed that PCF is not allowing free tier services post September 17, 2020 to play deploying the apps.

name                            total memory   instance memory   routes   service instances   paid plans   app instances   route ports                                                                                                                  
free                            0              0                 0        0                   disallowed   0               0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were never allowed to create new orgs on PWS using the cf cli. You were only ever allowed to create them through the Console. This is because of additional stipulations around requiring payment options to be set up for orgs & managing free trials.

That is irrelevant now though because PWS has been sunset. Here are the critical dates for the shutdown:

- New Pivotal Web Services account sign-ups will no longer be accepted after today, September 17, 2020.
- If you are consuming services offered through the AppDirect marketplace, please note that no new marketplace services will be available as of October 15, 2020.
- All existing AppDirect marketplace subscriptions will end on November 15, 2020.
- The end of availability (EOA) for Pivotal Web Services, effective as of January 15, 2021

For reference see this article:

https://blog.run.pivotal.io/pivotal-web-services-end-of-availability-announcement-and-timeline/

While the infrastructure for PWS still exists, it's very much closed to the public. That is why you cannot use the service anymore. Sorry.

If you are looking for migration options, I would encourage you to look at the [Cloud Foundry Organization's List of Certified Providers](https://www.cloudfoundry.org/certified-platforms/). This list has other public providers you can use and because all of these platforms are certified compatible with Cloud Foundry, you should be able to use continue your existing tooling and configuration files to deploy your apps there.